# How to bind pdo key and value from Question mark?

Tags: database, pdo

I want to make a query select data :

```
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, $options);
$query = "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = ?";
$pdo->prepare($query);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can PHP PDO Statements accept the table or column name as parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/182287/can-php-pdo-statements-accept-the-table-or-column-name-as-parameter)

Comment: It's Ok, But it's deference. If I follow that way when I echo $pdo It's will show ("SELECT dataname FROM tablename WHERE id = ?") is the same. What i need is if echo $pdo will show  "SELECT ? FROM ? WHERE ? = ?" for security.

If i use that function $query will convert to another.

Comment: Please read the answers from the link above to find out what options you have. What you are trying to do is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PDOpreapare statement is not support this query right row